# Does Google Cloud Datastore support partial update like Mongodb $set?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Node.js, and don't want to overwrite the whole entity with every little updates and most of the time just need to update a specific properties like a counter for example.

There is not obvious reference on how to do this in the docs.

Does Node.js version Google Cloud Datastore support partial update like Mongodb $set?

Comment: afaik, Datastore doesn't support partial update

Comment: This sucks.
But thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no DataStore API's to update an entity other than put() and putmulti(), so it is quiet impossible.

A bit of reading [from here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown) tells why.

> Internally, App Engine stores entities in protocol buffers, efficient mechanisms for serializing structured data; see the open source project page for more details. Instead of storing each entity property as an individual column in the corresponding Bigtable row, a single column is used which contains a binary-encoded protocol buffer containing the names and values for every property of a given entity.

In short, an entity row in a Datastore is a single binary value in the underlying storage scheme which is why there is no API for partial update.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct API to update just one property of an entity.

However, instead of getting the entity, modify it, and change it (using two different datastore API calls), you can use [Datastore transactions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions). It is the recommended way to achieve this atomically.

> A transaction is a set of Google Cloud Datastore operations on one or more entities. Each transaction is guaranteed to be atomic, which means that transactions are never partially applied. Either all of the operations in the transaction are applied, or none of them are applied.

The [example in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#uses_for_transactions) is explaining how to use transactions to "update an entity with a new property value relative to its current value:. Which is exactly what you are looking for.